Preprocessor assert function not acting as expected
This is a very quick question, I am learning OpenGL all thought that is irrelevant to the question it will just be very obvious in my code.
The issue I am having is that my assert macro will doesn't seem to detect the right value.
here is the code in question,
#define ASSERT(x) if (!x) __debugbreak();
#define GLCall(x) GLClearError();\
    x;\
    ASSERT(GLLogCall(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__))

Then where its called,
GLCall(int location = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "u_Color"));
ASSERT(location != -1);
GLCall(glUniform4f(location, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f));

When I debug the code it says the location is 0 but when I run it without a break point it asserts the break point. The weird part is that the assert macro works fine in the other macro that I posted. I'm sure its something simple that I'm missing. Anyways any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Try compiling with -E (for g++) to see the output of the preprocessor - that might help you see what is going on.

It's tradition to use x as (x) inside macros to avoid expansion weirdness. This might be the case here as that expands to if (!location != -1)

ASSERT(location != 1) expands to if (!location != 1) which (thanks to rules of precedence, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence ) is functionally equivalent to ``if ((!location) != 1)not toif (!(location != 1))that you seem to expect.   This is because the preprocessor does text substitution on code.   The fix is to change the macro to#define ASSERT(x) if (!(x)) __debugbreak();(not the extra()`)

An aside: due to having a semi-colon at the end of the definition of ASSERT() and multiple statements in GLCALL(), you'll get other unpleasant surprises when using the macros together (e.g.  if(x) GLCALL(x); else something_else(); ).    To combat those surprise, the usual approach is to do  #define ASSERT(x) do {if (!(x)) __debugbreak();} while (0)  and #define GLCALL(x) do {GLClearError(); x; ASSERT(GLLogCall(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__));} while (0)

Or just forget about the macro and use assert function from <cassert> header. Using macros in C++ is not recommended anyway
